# How can Ron disapparate safely but not apparate?

Tags: harry-potter

Ron was injured a couple of times from apparation but was never injured by disappartion, which is the how he found Hermione and Ron at white forest in *Harry Potter Deathly Hallows P1*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Apparation and Disapparation always go together

It's really one process. When you go from point A to point B, you Disapparate from A and Apparate to B. You can't *only* Apparate from nowhere, or *only* Disapparate to nowhere.

Comment: Exactly. The disapparation part it "entering the void", the apparation part is "exiting the void". You can't "stay in the void", as it were. So the question makes no sense.